# Curvature of Kawamata's singular hermitian metric has Poincaré growth?

Tags: kahler-einstein-metric

> Let $X,Y$ are two projective varieties and $f:X\to Y$ is an Iitaka
>   fibration. Consider the following singular hermitian metric
>   $$h(\sigma,\sigma)=\left(\int_{X_y}|\sigma|^{\frac{2}{m!}}\right)^{m!}$$
>   where $y\in Y$ and $\sigma$ is a section of $$\frac{1}{m!}f_*\mathcal
>  O_X(m!K_{X/Y})|_{X_y}$$
>
> then, the curvature of hermitian metric $h$, i.e.,
>   $\sqrt{-1}\Theta_h$  is of Poincaré growth ?

I am looking for direct proof without using Weil-Petersson geometry

Also what is the uniform lower bound of $h$ ?

> Now, if $\pi:X\to Y$ be a surjective holomorphic fibre space of
>   projective varieties $X,Y$ where the central fibre $X_0$ is Calabi-Yau
>   variety with canonical singularities, then the hermitian metric
>   $h$(can be seen as the inverse of volume) of $f^*\omega_Y\wedge 
>  \omega_{SF}^{m-1}$ has following expression ?
>
> $$h=O((\log \frac{1}{|\sigma_D|^n}))$$ where $\sigma_D$ is a local
>   defining section of discriminant locus $D$ of $\pi$ and $n$ is
>   positive integer. If this holds true, then $h$ has non-algebraic singularities.

**Definition of Semi-flat metric $\omega_{SF}$**: Fibrewise Semi-flat metric is a metric on total space $X$ such that its restriction to each fibre is Ricci flat metric(introduced by Yau-Vafa; See in bellow the construction of semi-flat metric).

The volume of fibers $\pi^{-1}(y)=X_y$ is a homological constant independent of $y$, and we assume that it is equal to $1$(when central fibre has canonical singularities, then the volume of fibers $\pi^{-1}(y)=X_y$ are bounded due to the result of M.Gross ). Since fibers are Calabi-Yau manifolds so $c_1(X_y)=0$, hence there is a smooth function $F_y$ such that $Ric(\omega_y)=\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}F_y$ and $\int_{X_y}(e^{F_y}-1)\omega_y^{n-m}=0$. The function $F_y$ vary smoothly in $y$. By Yau's
theorem there is a unique Ricci-flat K\"ahler metric $\omega_{SF,y}$ on $X_y$ cohomologous to $\omega_0$. So there is a smooth function $\rho_y$ on $\pi^{-1}(y)=X_y$
such that $\omega_0\mid_{X_y} +\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}\rho_y=\omega_{SF,y}$ is the unique Ricci-flat K\"ahler metric on
$X_y$. If we normalize by $\int_{X_y}\rho_y\omega_0^n\mid_{X_y}=0$  then
$\rho_y$
varies smoothly in $y$ and defines a smooth function $\rho$ on $X$ and we let

$$\omega_{SF}=\omega_0+\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar{\partial}\rho$$
which is called as Semi- flat metric.

Comment: The answer is yes, due to Paul Green estimate on Kawamata's Hermitian metric as $h(\sigma,\sigma)|_{X_t}=|t|^l(\log |t|)^m(1+o(1))$ and such hermitian metric are bounded if the central fiber $X_0$ has log terminal singularities from https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0012122

Comment: My previous comment at least tells us that the measure $\omega_{SRF}^\kappa\wedge \pi^*(\omega^n)$ is bounded if and only if central fiber $X_0$ has log terminal singularities. In fact the inverse of Kawamatas singular Hermitian metric gives a singular volume form which its ratio with $\omega_{SRF}^\kappa\wedge \pi^*(\omega^n)$ is positive constant , hence such measure are bounded iff the central fiber $X_0$ has log terminal singularities